# .NET Core equivalent of Uint8ClampedArray

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, uint8array

I'm using [jpeg_camera](https://amw.github.io/jpeg_camera/doc/class/Snapshot.html) library to get a snapshot from my webapp on my laptop and, by a fetch call, send it to my controller.

`snapshot.get_image_data` returns an object with 3 properties (data: Uint8ClampedArray, width, heigh).

When I do the fetch call `sendPic(data)` I always get a 400 Error, because the `ModelState` is not valid.
That means `Byte[]` is not good for `Uint8ClampedArray` from JS.

What is the equivalent for that object?

I've found also a method that return a base64 and I can convert it inside the controller into a `Byte[]` but I'd like to avoid this solution.

the JS code:

```
function savePic() {
    var test1 = snapshot.get_image_data((done) => {
        var data = {
            "Pic": done.data,
            "IdActivity": idActivity,
            "Instant": new Date().toISOString()
        };
        sendPic(data);
    });
}

function sendPic(data) {
    fetch(uriPicsEndPoint, {
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'POST'
    });
}
```

The API Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SavePic([FromBody] Selfie selfie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_configuration["ConnectionStrings:Storage"]);
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var camerasContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("selfies");
            await camerasContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            var id = Guid.NewGuid();
            var fileExtension = ".jpeg";
            var blobName = $"{selfie.IdActivity}/{id}{fileExtension}";
            var blobRef = camerasContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

            await blobRef.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(selfie.Pic, 0, selfie.Pic.Length);
            string sas = blobRef.GetSharedAccessSignature(
                new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
                {
                    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
                });
            var blobUri = $"{blobRef.Uri.AbsoluteUri}{sas}";

            var notification = new UpdateSelfieRequest()
            {
                UriPic = blobUri,
                IdActivity = selfie.IdActivity,
                Instant = selfie.Instant
            };

            string serviceBusConnectionString = _configuration["ConnectionStrings:ServiceBus"];
            string queueName = _configuration["ServiceBusQueueName"];
            IQueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(serviceBusConnectionString, queueName);
            var messageBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notification);
            var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));
            await queueClient.SendAsync(message);
            await queueClient.CloseAsync();

            return Ok();
        }
        catch
        {
            return StatusCode(500);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

And the CLASS "Selfie":

```
public class Selfie
{
    public Byte[] Pic { get; set; }
    public int IdActivity { get; set; }
    public DateTime Instant { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post what's actually being sent? You can see that in the Network tab of the Developer Tools in most browsers

Comment: Well, [Uint8ClampedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray) is an 8 Bit Unsigned Integer (0-255), like a [Byte type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/byte).

Comment: As a quick guess, if you're using `JSON.stringify` then the parameter should be type JObject?

Comment: @Mark G [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) should be a JSON string in the form of an array of byte values (in relation to the `Pic` member). `JSON.Deserialize` should get it right.

Comment: @Jimi But with model binding the deserialization is done for you.  My suggestion was to define parameter as `[FromBody] JObject selfie` so you could see the raw data (like Pic as an array of byte values) which could be converted by using `selfie["Pic"].Values<byte>()`.

Comment: @Mark G  Ah yes, of course. You're right.

Comment: I will post the screenshot of the object sent from dev tools:
[link](https://ibb.co/f6k9E8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use stringify it becomes `{"0":255, "1":0, "2":0, "3":255, ...}` in the JSON.

If you have your action parameter defined as `JObject selfie` you could get bytes using `var pic = selfie["Pic"].ToObject<Dictionary<int, byte>>()`.

Alternatively you could post data as form values and define action as `SavePic(Dictionary<int, byte> Pic, int IdActivity, DateTime Instant)` using the following code in browser to test:

```
var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(5, 5, 5, 5);

$.post('SavePic', {
    Pic: ctx.getImageData(5, 5, 5, 5).data,
    IdActivity: 1,
    Instant: new Date().toISOString()
});
```

However it may be easier to convert the Uint8ClampedArray to regular array before posting data.